# Compilation of Flex 3.0 Application

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

How to develop and compile a [Flex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flex) application without [Flex Builder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flash_Builder)?

Comment: You want to develop it or to compile it?

Answer (score 3):

Try:

- [Flex 3 sdk command line development](http://asantoso.wordpress.com/2008/05/18/flex-3-sdk-command-line-development-with-example-on-linux/)
- [Flex on the command line](http://onflash.org/ted/2005/01/flex-on-command-line.php)
- [Adobe - Coding with MXML and ActionScript](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/quickstart/coding_with_mxml_and_actionscript/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use Eclipse with the Flex Builder plugin.  There's also [FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=Main_Page), but I haven't used it.